# Ryacas library in R does not work

Tags: r, math

`install.packages(c("Ryacas))`

was used to install the library in R. No issued in installation and md5 was fine. All necessary package were installed.

`library(Ryacas)`

yields

`Loading required package: XML`

`x <- Sym("x")`
`Limit(sin(x)/x, x, 0)`

for example, however, yields

```
[1] "Starting Yacas!"
Error in socketConnection(host = "127.0.0.1", port = 9734, server = FALSE,  : 
cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In socketConnection(host = "127.0.0.1", port = 9734, server = FALSE,  :
127.0.0.1:9734 cannot be opened
```

What do I need to do to get this library to run, on windows XP, using standard R, via Rstudio front end?

By the way, why do these ports need to be open?

Comment: Make sure you aren't running a firewall on your machine that blocks those ports.

Comment: Read the Troubleshooting section on the Ryacas home page.  Maybe you installed Ryacas but not yacas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ryacas is ([quoting](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Ryacas/))

> An interface to the yacas computer algebra system.

so it expects `yacas` to be installed and up and running. It does not install `yacas` itself just the `R` libraries needed to use it through `R`.

The library offers a script to install `yacas` on your computer ; it is name `yacasInstall` (See page 9 of [the manual](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Ryacas/Ryacas.pdf))

Running `?yacas` should give you more information.

Also, do not forget to actually start `yacas` by running  `yacas --server 9734` in the directory where `yacas` was installed.

Comment: See also [this other SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8794614/r-trouble-making-package-ryacas-to-work-on-windows)